# How fast can I deploy to Ropsten?

Tags: contract-development, ropsten, truffle-deployment

Does anyone know how fast I can deploy to the Ropsten network?

I am using the following command:

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

and I have an instance of geth running.

In the geth console, when I run `txpool.status` (before I run the truffle migrate command), together with the txpool.status command, I get the following output:

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 1991,
  queued: 0
}
```

Do I have to wait until all 1991 transactions are completed before my contract gets deployed/migrated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My contracts usually deploy within minutes on Ropsten, so it shouldn't take too long.  If you just want to test deployed contracts it will be quicker and easier to just run your own private chain for testing.  Some good instructions for starting a private local chain are [here](https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

Whether or not you have to wait for all those pending transactions to finish is probably dependent on how much you pay for gas, but the wait for normal pricing shouldn't be too long.  I've never had to wait longer than five minutes to deploy a contract on the Ropsten test chain.

Cheers

Comment: Hi jojeyh, can you do a simple test to deploy and let me know how long it takes? I've tests running for nearly 4 hours already, and not 1 has succeeded yet. I'm wondering if Ropsten is under attack.

Comment: I was also having problems with Ropsten at the end of last week, things that had previously been reliably deploying in a minute or so were failing completely. So it seems like an attack or a bug or something...